# How can I escape string with a regex?

Tags: regex

How can I escape a string to improve queries in MySQL.

I need  add ` (crass) in names of tables with name of fields separatly by dot.

But sometimes exists more than one

Examples of my strings

How write a regex to do this

Table.field
   `Table`.`field` // <-- need this

```
FORMAT(Table.field + Table2.field2 - Table3.field3, 2)
FORMAT(`Table`.`field` + `Table2`.`field2` - `Table3`.`field3`, 2) // <-- need this

DATE(Table.field)
DATE(`Table`.`field`) // <-- need this

Table.field > Table2.field
`Table`.`field` > `Table2`.`field` // <-- need this
```

Comment: What tool/language are you using?

Comment: That's quite a complex task and I don't think a simple regex would work for it. Most likely you need to programmatically parse the SQL.

Comment: You should be doing this while you are creating the query, not after the fact. Escaping is generally impossible after the fact, except in very specific limited circumstances.

Comment: Find: `(\w+)\.(\w+)` ... Replace: ``$1.$2``

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tested all 3 examples and it worked correctly. It's more simple than I tought. Thank you!

Comment: @Claytinho Glad to help you.  I think you are just trying to format some offline queries but everyone beat up on you for trying to do this in the app layer which you aren't doing.

Comment: @deceze First of all thanks for your concern. 
Just for record I've replaced a single piece of the query, not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find: (\w+).(\w+) ... Replace: $1.$2 – Tim Biegeleisen